# Linux Driver Development - Can I seriously harm my system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

I am currently reading a book about driver development for Linux.
Now I started writing a driver for the razer naga mouse.

My question is, what is the worst case scenario in driver development?
(I am not touching any CPU, Hard disk, Ram etc.)

I always thought the worst thing that could happen is that I crash the system and have to reboot it then. Before I continue writing code, I would like to make sure I can't seriously harm my system.

Comment: Short answer: that's correct. I can't really think of any instances where you'd risk frying hardware or bricking your PC.  Embedded system development: yes.  Playing with a mouse driver for PC Linux - no.  I think you're safe.

Comment: Probably... but not certainly.  Anything running in kernel context is theoretically above most protections, so something like trashing a hard drive partition is certainly possible - and harder to recover things like corrupting a bios or secure element are in theory possible.  But most innocent learner mistakes that don't touch critical systems will simply crash the run attempt.

Comment: Theoretically you can [set fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp0_on_fire) to things...

Comment: Thank you very much. Almost every tutorial and the author of the book itself recommends to be careful. The problem is that those warnings are very serious. But anyway, I will try to not set any printer on fire @Marc B or blow up my mouse :D

Comment: Testing your kernel code inside a virtual machine would provide another layer of protection for most of the hosting system - though not for connected-through USB peripherals with real-world side effects.

Comment: Another caution you can make is by having a your driver as _loadable module_ instead of _built-in_. That way if you mess up things, you could just restart normally and fix it and then _re-insert_. On the other hand, in __extreme case__ , having an in-built module __may__ cause your OS to crash on boot !

Comment: Who knows [what could happen](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Booting-Linux-using-UEFI-can-brick-Samsung-laptops-1793958.html) when you mess around in kernel space?

Answer (score 2):

Hardware nowadays is pretty redundant. It is very hard to break hardware using software(heating issues aside).

Worst case scenario is you brick your system and might have to reinstall the OS. This can happen pretty easily during device driver development. You have file system drivers in the kernel and your drivers might corrupt the kernel stack which might leave it in an unusable state.

The linux kernel has pretty good safety measures built in, like dropping to read only mode once the kernel is corrupted. This mounts your root file system in read only mode so that you cannot trash it.

So, always be on the safe side. Try to develop in a VM like Virtualbox which gives you pretty much everything nowadays.